# what does `webpack` cli `--debug` option mean?

Tags: webpack

Here is the command:

```
webpack --debug
```

Or, within `webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {...},
  debug: true  //what thing does this option do?
}
```

I read the `webpack` doc, but there is no explanation about the `--debug` option.

Comment: It switches to debug mode.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But what's debug mode mean? How can I find something different within `bundle` or some `work flow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debug option is deprecated since webpack 2.0 that must be done wihin modules.rules